# Is it possible to increase video gamma or brightness at container level?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, filter

I would like to know if is it possible to increase the brightness or gamma of a video without full re-encoding. For example some versions of ffmpeg allow certain special bitstream filters described here - presumed we have a h264 video - : http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=152419 which can alter some of the video characteristics without re-encoding the video. Some containers also can store such a meta information about the video gamma or brightness, as far as I know matroska, and QuickTime, and maybe there are some video players too which can deal with this information.
I know that a similar modification, namely cropping the video is possible without a full re-encode merely by setting the cropping information at container level. For example such a video uploaded to youtube are cropped at the values which were set at the container level. So this could be a quick fix for unneeded logos and black bars.

Comment: Which codec and which container?

Comment: Any! I would like to know, with which codec and container is it possible. Maybe with H264 by manipulating the video data in a clever way? Or with matroska by setting / adding the necessery meta tags? I have no clue.

Comment: This would be really useful if it were possible. The only container/codec that I know you can do it with is dng sequences, which can have exposure and colour grading information in the metadata or as a sidecar file. But not exactly a useful delivery format.